# Single computation of a variable that has to be visible for every thread

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I am computing a project with openMP. In this project i need to do a computation, in particular:

```
gap = (DEFAULT_HEIGHT / nthreads);
```

where `DEFAULT_HEIGHT` is a constant and `nthreads`  is the number of threads inside my parallel region. My problem is that i can't compute the variable `gap`  outside the parallel region because i need to be inside to know `nthreads`  . But on the other hand i don't want to compute `gap`  for every thread. Moreover i can't set a code like this:

```
if(tid==0){
    gap = (DEFAULT_HEIGHT / nthreads);
}
```

because i don't know the order of esecution of every thread, so it could be that the thread 0 start for last and all my other computation that need `gap` will be wrong ( because it will be not setted ). So, there is a way to make this computation only once without this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that `gap` is a shared variable and enclose it in an OpenMP `single` directive, something like

```
#pragma omp single
{ 
    gap = (DEFAULT_HEIGHT / nthreads);
}
```

Only one thread will execute the code enclosed in the `single` directive, the other threads will wait at the end of the enclosed block of code.

An alternative would be to make `gap` private and let all threads compute their own value.  This might be faster, the `single` option requires some synchronisation which always takes time.  If you are concerned, try both and compare results. ( I think this is what ComicSansMS is suggesting.)

Comment: Yeah, i think the same about the answer of ComicsSansMS. But also keeping the gap shared and do the computation for every thread doesn't change the time of compute, i think. However i'm trying this, as soon as i will compare the results i will give you my answer. In every case, thanks for your answer

Comment: @Smat, if the overhead introduced by the `single` construct really matters for the performance of your code, then it is not a good candidate for OpenMP parallelisation in the first place.

Comment: Is it even necessary or helpful to use single here?  It's a race condition but every thread will write the same value.  I doubt that's any slower than requiring them to sync and wait for single.  The best is probably just to make `gap` private and have each tread calculate the same value.

Comment: @Zboson: no, I see no necessity for sharing `gap` but OP writes *i don't want to compute gap for every thread*.  Maybe the code sample posted gives a too-simple idea of what is really going on.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the tradeoff: If only one thread does the computation you have to synchronize access to that value. In particular also threads that only want to read the value do have to synchronize, as they usually have no other means of determining whether the write is already finished. If initialization of the variable is so expensive that it can compensate for this, you should go for it. But it's probably not.

Keep in mind that you can do a lot of computation on the CPU in the time it takes to fetch data from memory. Synchronizing this access properly will eat away additional cycles and can lead to undesired stalling effects. Even worse, the impact of such effects usually increases drastically with the number of threads sharing the resource.

It's not uncommon to accept some redundancy in parallel computation as the synchronization overhead easily nullifies any benefits from saved computation time for redundant data.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. The performances of my program it's something that i have to consider for the goals of it. So i will try the solution of High Performance Mark and later i will try to compare what is better for the computing time, if with or without.